# Async Https Request in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying the whole day to get some https request running.

My code so far does not work, after calling it, i am running in an "Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Function.entries"

```js
import * as https from "https";

function openRequest(options : any)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const request = https.request(options).on('response', (response : any) => {
            resolve(response);
        }).on('error', (error : any) => {
            reject(error);
        });

        request.end();
    });
}
```

I have to use a default library, so another one won't do the work.

Can someone tell me where i am dooing something wrong?

Comment: You don't call `entries` in that code you shared, nor do I see any recursion there which is likely to cause that error. Are you sure this code is the part that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't end the request before the response is received?

Comment: @Quentin My whole code is just this. Plus the option definition of course, but yes.

Comment: @caTS from that what i know, i have to call this function to start the request.

Comment: @caTS — [end](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#requestenddata-encoding-callback) finishes sending the request. It's needed.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this stuff to run, typescript isn't my native language and i really don't won't to make my living out of it but some stranger in the internet used to "await for" the res object in a loop:

```js
const request = https.request(options, async (res : any) => {

  res.setEncoding("utf-8");

  let result = "";

  for await (const chunk of res)
  {
    result += chunk;
  }

  resolve(result);
}).on("error", (error) => {
  reject(error);
});

request.end();
```

I really don't know, if on("error"...) will work, because .on("response"...) has failed so far. But at least, in a good day at full moon, this code runs.

Comment: This code resolves the promise to the _body_ of the HTTP response object, whereas the code in your question resolves the promise to the HTTP response object itself. Didn't know you can use `for await` with readable streams, therefore +1.